# Springboot @ConfigurationProperties load list from yaml not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to load list of string from yaml file but the list is empty on my test

when i debug i see the list is empty

Here is yaml application-reasons-mapping.yml

```
credit-decision-reasons:
      - reason-code: 'D0001'
        description:  reason 1
      - reason-code: '00002'
        description: reason 2
      - reason-code: '00003'
        description: reason 3
      - reason-code: '00004'
        description: reason 5
```

Configuration file

```java
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CreditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties.CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties.class)
@Profile("reasons-mapping")
public class CreditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties {

    private List<CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties> creditDecisionReasons = new ArrayList<>();

    @Data
    @ConfigurationProperties("credit-decision-reasons")
    public static class CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties {
        private String reasonCode;
        private String description;
    }

}
```

Test file

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("reasons-mapping")
class CreditDecisionReasonsMappingPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private CreditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties creditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties;

     @Test
     public void testCreditDecisionReasonsMapping_loading_succesfully() {

     System.out.println(creditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties.getCreditDecisionReasons().get(0).getReasonCode());

     assertTrue(creditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties.getCreditDecisionReasons().get(0).getReasonCode().equals("0001"));

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in the above approach, which need some changes in yaml file and as well as code

1) Properties in yaml file are wrong indented, they need outer class name as root which is prefix in `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation

```
 credit-decision-reasons-mapping-properties:
   credit-decision-reason-mapping-properties: 
    - reason-code: D0001
      description: reason 1
    - reason-code: 00002
      description: reason 2
    - reason-code: 00003
      description: reason 3
    - reason-code: 00004
      description: reason 5
```

2) Since you have mentioned classes in `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation all of these class need to be annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`

3) `ArrayList` should need to be matched with sub property name in yaml file

```
@Data
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CreditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties.
CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties.class)
@ConfigurationProperties("credit-decision-reasons-mapping-properties")
public class CreditDecisionReasonsMappingProperties {

@Getter
private List<CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties> creditDecisionReasonMappingProperties;

@Data
@ConfigurationProperties
public static class CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties {
    private String reasonCode;
    private String description;
     }

 }
```

Comment: After making the above changes i am getting null on my test, which means the properties are still not loading

Comment: Apologies . the solution works,Thanks. i forgot to change the class name "CreditDecisionReasonMappingProperties"